# How to display all posts with all its comments - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to rails and don't know how to achieve this in rails. It might be a really stupid question. But it was not covered in the RoR [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com) course I did and could not fint a answer elsewhere.

So I have two tables, posts and comments that have an one-to-many relationship. One post has many comments.

I want to display all post with all its comments underneath. What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

**First**: you can do like this way in your post controller action (**suppose :index**) do:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

And in your **index.html.erb**

```
<% @posts.each do |post|%>
  # Your post attribute like name etc
  <% post.comments.each do |comment|%>
    # Your post attribute like name etc
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Second**: in your post controller action  do:

```
 def index
   @posts = Post.all.includes(:comments)
 end
```

And in your **index.html.erb**

```
<% @posts.each do |post|%>
  # Your post attribute like name etc
  <% post.comments.each do |comment|%>
    # Your post attribute like name etc
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Difference in above two ways is that in first one there is always a data base call when you do **"post.comments"** but in second there is only two data base call i.e. **"Post.all.includes(:comments)"**, no data base call at view part, so it is up to you which way you want to use.

Comment: actually using `#includes` will do 2 database calls not 1, one for all posts and one for all comments.

Answer (score 0):

If a Post has_many comments then:

```
post = Post.find(1)
post.comments.each do |comment|
  # do something with each comment here
end
```